# How to refactor/fix algorithim from mutating a reference to using inline variable

Tags: javascript, algorithm

The function takes an input path like `a.b.c` and should output a nested structure json like:

```
{
   a: {
      b: {
         c: {}
      }
   }
}
```

The algorithm using iterative style is:

```
function stringToObj(path, obj) {
  var parts = path.split(".");
  var part;
  while ((part = parts.shift())) {
    if (typeof obj[part] != "object") obj[part] = {};
    obj = obj[part]; // line 6
  }
}
```

Current usage:

```
let result = {};
stringToObj("a.b.c", result);
console.log(result); // outputs the json
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efps26wq/)

### The problem:

It relies mutating the obj parameter on line 6.
I would like to not rely upon passing the `result` object, and rather create one inside the function. Doing so results in different results. A desired example usage:

```
const result = stringToObj("a.b.c"); // result should be the json
```

### Context:

The exercise is for learning purpose. Main objective is understanding why removing `obj` and rewriting the function as per follows doesn't work as expected:

```
function stringToObj(path) {
  var obj = {};
  var parts = path.split(".");
  var part;
  while ((part = parts.shift())) {
    if (typeof obj[part] != "object") obj[part] = {};
    obj = obj[part]; // line 6
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Added context as per suggestion!

Comment: My take: nothing to refactor here. [Wrong audience for almost all How-Tos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @greybeard This function could have been implemented using recursion, DIY iterative style using stack, using while with inline shift(), and finally using `reduce` function. It touches a multitude of aspects around performance, memory footprint, readability, extension points etc. I am glad that some members are very bright and can see through all the constraints without much effort. I am not one of those and answers like these are game changers. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After splitting by `.`s, you can use `reduceRight` to start at the last property, `c`, while taking an initial value of an empty object. Inside the callback, use a computed property to return a new object containing the old object at the property being iterated over:

```js
const stringToObj = str => str.split('.').reduceRight(
  (lastObj, prop) => ({ [prop]: lastObj }), {}
);
console.log(stringToObj('a.b.c'));
```

If you're not familiar with it, `reduceRight` is like `reduce`, except that it iterates starting from the last element in the array and going backwards, instead of starting from the first element of the array and going forwards. On each iteration, the callback is called, where the first argument (here, `lastObj`) is the value returned from the *last* iteration, and the second argument is the current item of the array being iterated over.

You can also `reverse` the array of properties and use `reduce` instead of `reduceRight`, which might be easier to understand at a glance, but it's a bit less elegant:

```js
const stringToObj = str => str.split('.').reverse().reduce(
  (lastObj, prop) => ({ [prop]: lastObj }), {}
);
console.log(stringToObj('a.b.c'));
```

Also, don't mix `var` and `let`. If you're going to use ES2015 syntax - *which you should* - consider always using `const`, and only use `let` [when you must reassign](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6). Never use `var`, it has too many gotchas to be worth using in modern code.

Comment: Wow amazing how reduce didn't cross my mind. Its so simple and elegant.

Comment: Would I trouble too much to ask why inlining the variable doesn't work? Otherwise i feel that problem is solved but without knowing the why's. Thank you much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean, "inlining the variable"?

Comment: Instead of passing `obj` as second parameter with a value of `{}`, have the function handle the creation of this `result` object inside, and return it.

Comment: I don't understand what code you're thinking of, do you mean by iterating over the props manually and reassigning the parent object? That's possible too, just not so elegant

Comment: Agree with the elegance aspect. However i desperately want to understand the internals, i've updated the question with a `Context` section and an example. Thanks!

Comment: You need to save a reference to the original outer object created, else when you return, you're returning the *inner* object. `var origObj = {};
  var obj = origObj;` then `return origObj` at the end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107510/discussion-between-cristian-e-and-certainperformance).